# NodeJS stream pausing/resuming does not work with XMLHttpRequest, but works with curl?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, xmlhttprequest, arraybuffer

This is a pretty esoteric issue that I can't produce a small test case for, so sorry in advance. But maybe someone has run into something like it previously.

I have code like this (using restify):

```
server.put("/whatever", function (serverRequest, serverResponse, next) {
    serverRequest.pause();

    serverRequest.on("data", function (chunk) {
        console.log("from outside", chunk);
    });

    doSomeAsyncStuff(function (err) {
        serverRequest.on("data", function (chunk) {
            console.log("from inside", chunk);
        });
        serverRequest.on("end", function () {
            next();
        });

        serverRequest.resume();
    });
});
```

When I hit this server using CURL, this works great. But when I hit it with XMLHttpRequest, I get one less `"from inside"` log line than I do `"from outside"` log lines. It seems one of the data events is getting lost, despite my best efforts to pause ASAP.

---

Here is the CURL command I am using:

```
curl -X PUT -T file.pdf http://localhost:7070/whatever -v
```

And here is the `XMLHttpRequest` code (works in recent versions of Chrome):

```
var arrayBuffer = fromElsewhere();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("PUT", "http://localhost:7070/whatever");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", arrayBuffer.byteLength);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
xhr.send(arrayBuffer);
```

One notable difference is that CURL seems to send `Expect: 100-continue` before uploading, whereas `XMLHttpRequest` does not. I tried adding that header manually but of course it didn't actually do much (i.e. Chrome did not wait for a response, it just sent up all the PDF data along with the original request). Even so, I don't know why this would effect things.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this ? If I can really pause/ resume http response using nodejs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat predictably, this didn't have anything to do with curl vs. `XMLHttpRequest`, but instead with [the fact that `serverRequest.pause` is only advisory; it doesn't actually pause right away](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/yv6Dl-O-wYk/zeW6jKdZ8EwJ). That is, it's pretty much useless.

So presumably in the CURL case the timing was nice enough that `pause` actually worked as expected, whereas in the `XMLHttpRequest` case the timing was off, and one of the `"from outside"` `data` events managed to slip through the "advisory" pause.

There are apparently various fixes for this, discussed in the thread, but I'm still pretty shaky on this whole streams/buffers universe so I won't try to recommend one in this answer.

I've added a [documentation pull request](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/2989) in the hopes nobody else tries to use `pause` assuming that it actually works.

Comment: Well, `pause` *works* but as you mention, it's advisory, and asynchronous. A very useful use-case of `pause` is within a proxy: you read from upstream, and write to the client. If the write to the client returns `false`, it means that the buffer is full, and you can send a `pause` to the backend. You will probably receive a few extra chunks of data from the backend, but not *all* the file. Without the pause, proxying a 1 GB file causes the whole file to be buffered into memory (and your Node.js process to explode). I hope this helps!